# How to load/enable r.stream.distance and r.lfp in QGIS 3.6.1 with GRASS 7.6.1 (Windows 10)?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, add-ons

I am new to QGIS and GRASS. I would like to use r.lfp in QGIS with GRASS.

So far I installed addons extensions r.stream.distance and r.lfp in GRASS (Settings/Addons extension/Install extension from addons [g.extension]), without checking the two optional check boxes (system-wide and verbose).

I was hoping opening QGIS with GRASS after that would allow me to see the two new raster commands in QGIS with GRASS (Processing Toolbox/GRASS/Raster (r.*)). But this is not the case.

Any idea what I am missing and how to correct it?